# ContextFilterQuery is not working Solr suggest

Tags: solr, content-search

I recently tried Solr autosuggest search in my local,

Steps I followed :

1. Added configuration in master in `sensoft_master_index\conf\solrconfig.xml`

   ```
   <requestHandler name="/suggest" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
       <lst name="defaults">
           <str name="suggest">true</str>
           <str name="suggest.count">10</str>
       </lst>
       <arr name="components">
           <str>suggest</str>
       </arr>
   </requestHandler>
   ```

   and search component

   ```
   <searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
       <lst name="suggester">
           <str name="name">default</str>
           <str name="lookupImpl">AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory</str>
           <str name="field">_name</str>
           <str name="contextField">_template</str>
           <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">text_general</str>
           <str name="buildOnStartup">true</str>
       </lst>
   </searchComponent>
   ```
2. in C# code, I tried to filter the suggestions based on the template ID using `ContextFilterQuery` Parameter in the `SuggestParameters` and suggestion is not working, but the Suggestions are coming when I remove the `ContextFilterQuery` parameter in the `SuggestParameters`.

Attaching the code

```
ID template = new ID("1930BBEB-7805-471A-A3BE-4858AC7CF696");
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"D:\test.txt", template.Guid.ToString("N"));
using (var context = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("sitecore_master_index").CreateSearchContext())
{
    SolrSuggestQuery query = term;
    var options = new SuggestHandlerQueryOptions
    {
        Parameters = new SuggestParameters
        {
            Count = 5,
            ContextFilterQuery= template.Guid.ToString("N")
        }
    };

    // if (!template.IsNull)
    // options.Parameters.ContextFilterQuery = template.Guid.ToString("N");                    
    // options.Parameters.ContextFilterQuery = "/sitecore/content";
    var result = context.Suggest(query, options);
    suggestedList = result.Suggestions["default"].Suggestions.Select(a => a.Term).ToList();
}
```

Comment: can you try by adding `<str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>` in your search component after `lookupImpl`?

Comment: pl share the search query from search.log file